# Prevent adding two items with the same byte[] key in from being added to a KeyedCollection<byte[], MyObject>

Tags: c#, arrays, iequalitycomparer

Code:

```
public class Coll : KeyedCollection<byte[], MyObject>
{
    protected override byte[] GetKeyForItem(MyObject item) => item.Key;
    
}

public class EquComparer : IEqualityComparer<byte[]>
{
    public bool Equals(byte[]? x, byte[]? y)
    {
        if (x is null && y is null) return true;
        if (x is null) return false;
        if (y is null) return false;
        return x.SequenceEqual(y);
    }

    public int GetHashCode([DisallowNull] byte[] obj)
    {
        int result = Int32.MinValue;
        foreach (var b in obj)
        {
            result += b;
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

My key is `byte[]`. I want to set the default equality comparer to compare keys with to something using `byte[]::SequenceEqual()` to keep two items with the same keys from being added.

Is there a way to do this?

**Edit:** As other have pointed out I could use the constructor to specify a non default equality comparer. I am certain it will be forgotten at some point giving rise to a bug that will be difficult to find. That is why I want to add some code to the class that makes my custom equality comparer the default for that class.

Comment: Disregarding everything else, you have tried using the constructor for the comparer no? `public Coll():base(new EquComparer()) { }` ?

Comment: "makes my custom equality comparer the default for that class." - but the class you want to be the "default" for is `byte[]` - a built-in generated type, that knows nothing of your code and shouldn't start behaving differently *everywhere* inside your process (for e.g. library methods working with such arrays)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `KeyedCollection<TKey,TItem>` class has a [constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.keyedcollection-2.-ctor#System_Collections_ObjectModel_KeyedCollection_2__ctor_System_Collections_Generic_IEqualityComparer__0__) that accepts an `IEqualityComparer<TKey>`. You could invoke this constructor when instantiating the derived class:

```
public class Coll : KeyedCollection<byte[], MyObject>
{
    public Coll() : base(new EquComparer()) { }

    protected override byte[] GetKeyForItem(MyObject item) => item.Key;
}
```

Comment: This is the answer. Thank you!